# Identifying test projects from solution file

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, project, solution

Assume that I have a visual studio solution file. I want to know how can i identify the test projects from that solution file.
Is there any way to identify that.?

Answer (score 1):

If you have created the unit test using Visual Studio, and haven't changed the default name, VS2012 will add '.Tests' suffix to the Project name.
Also in VS2012, you get a different image for Tests in the solution explorer.[image]

Comment: @stf would you mind marking it as answer if it helped? So that future visitors can have an idea.

Answer (score 0):

If you open the project file using notepad, you'll find nodes specifying the type of the project:

```
<IsCodedUITest>False</IsCodedUITest>
<TestProjectType>UnitTest</TestProjectType>
```